# Is it possible to hide the caption (a.k.a. titlebar) of a top-level frame?

Tags: wxwidgets

I've tried, but in vain, setting the window style of a `wxFrame` to `(wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & (~wxCAPTION))`. The title bar is still stubbornly there. My platform is Linux MX-19.4_x64, and the wxWidgets port is wxGTK 3.1.5. Any suggestion? Thanks.

By the way, I'm aware of the method `wxNonOwnedWindow::SetShape`, but I prefer to not use it, because the purpose is as simple as hiding the titlebar, instead of changing the shape to a triangle, a star or something.

Comment: `wxFrame* frame = new wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, wxString(), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0L)` works for me on linux mint.  But it does seem that almost any flag other than 0L will bring the title bar back - even ones like `wxRESIZE_BORDER` which seem unrelated to the title bar.

Comment: @Cody, not all styles can be set dynamically. I believe the documentation stares it somewhere.

Comment: @Cody, also if you are trying it in a constructor as `New Pagodi`, you also need to turn off maximize/minimize box as they are located on the title bar and let the title bar to appear.

Comment: Using 0L but still have the title bar... wxWidgets 3.2.4 with GTK+3...